# @webMvcTest is not excluding and loading beans marked as @Repository

Tags: spring, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I've a `@RestController`  which has only one dependency in field `@Autowire`
that dependency is @component, that component Class definition has some autowired fields which are @service and those services have some @repositories.

In this whole flow I've kafka, Quartz, Cassandra and DB2
So when I was creating a Unit test case for my controller, I dont want to setup whole application. so I decided to use @webMvcTest and used @MockBean on  my only one dependency of controller  class.

But my Test is throwing and exception because its trying to create a Dao bean, which is marked as @repository.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyControllerTest .class)
class MyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    MyControllerDependency dependency;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void test_something() throws Exception {
       assert(true);
    }
}
```

Here is oversimplified version of code

```
@Component
class MyControllerDependency { 
    @AutoiWired
    MyCustomService service;
}

@Service
class MyCustomService{

   @Autowired
   MyCustomDao dao;
}

@Repository
class MyCustomDao{
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;
}
```

I'm getting following exception in test.

```
Exception

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field template in com.....MyCustomDao`  required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found.
```

Question is, When I'm using `@WebMvcTest` slice and already mocking the only required dependency `MyControllerDependency`  then why spring test context is trying to load `MyCustomDao` which is annotated as  `@Repository`.

I can do integration testing with `SpringbootTest` & `AutoconfigureMockMVC`, but for writing Junit test just for controller, I need to use `WebMvcTest` slice. which is creating a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have any `@ComponentScan("...")` annotation active on your `@SpringBootApplication`?

As described in [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.user-configuration-and-slicing):

> Another source of confusion is classpath scanning. Assume that, while you structured your code in a sensible way, you need to scan an additional package. Your application may resemble the following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.app", "com.example.another" })
public class MyApplication {

    // ...

}
```

> Doing so effectively overrides the default component scan directive with the side effect of scanning those two packages regardless of the slice that you chose. For instance, a @DataJpaTest seems to suddenly scan components and user configurations of your application. Again, moving the custom directive to a separate class is a good way to fix this issue.

One solution is to create a seperate `@Configuration` that is annotated with `@ComponentScan`. When creating a `@WebMvcTest` the configuration (and its component scan is ignored).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.another")
public class DbConfig {
}
```

Answer (score 27):

I ran into a similar problem where I want to test only my controller using @WebMvcTest, but the spring context was trying to create nondependent spring beans and was failing as below.

Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'TestController' defined in file ...

Solution: load only the controller your testing for an example like `@ContextConfiguration(classes = DemoController.class)`.
Also, find below a complete sample

```java
    @WebMvcTest
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = DemoController.class)  
    public class DemoControllerTest {    
        @Autowired
        MockMvc mockMvc;

        @MockBean
        DemoService demoService;

        @Test
        public void testGetAllProductCodes_withOutData() throws Exception {
            when(productCodeService.getAllProductCodes())
                    .thenReturn(new ArrayList<ProductCodes>());
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/services/productCodes"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isNoContent());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I lost access to that code repo due to client change :) But I'll test the similar scenario and let you know how it goes... Thanks for the update though

Comment: why in the freaking world `@ContextConfiguration(classes = DemoController.class)` works and `@WebMvcTest(controllers = DemoController.class)` does not, is beyond me. This was really helpful. thank you.

Comment: @Eugene Did you figure out why ContextConfiguration works but WebMvcTest does not?

Comment: @JustvanderVeeken I did not, sorry mate.

Comment: @JustvanderVeeken @Eugene Found here on spring's source and debugging. At class/method `SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext`, if you don't use `ContextConfiguration` then at `TestContext` instance, field `mergedContextConfiguration.classes` it will point to your app's main class instead of your controller, and thus it will use set-up of your main class (at least to some extent).

Comment: why excludeFilters in @WebMvcTest not work as expected?

Answer (score 5):

This usually happens when you have explicit @ComponentScan annotation on the spring boot main application class.

The @ComponentScan annotation suppresses the default component scanning mechanism that happens with @Webmvctest where it scans up the package hierarchy and apply excludeFilters to find only controller and its related classes.

Comment: Thanks @Kumar_V, Yeah my internal company framework has a default microservice Application class, which all microservice application extends,,,, and this parent class has component scan defined for com.company.domain. and I cant remove it .  Is there still a workaround to use the slice testing ?

Answer (score 0):

When you mock your bean using `@MockBean` annotation you should define what that mocked bean should do when you call it's method, you usually do this using `when` in Mockito. In your case it can be done this way:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebMvcTest
class MyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    MyControllerDependency dependency;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void test_something() throws Exception {
        when(dependency.sample()).thenReturn("Hello, Mock");
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/test/restpoint")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
               .andDo(print())
               .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

At this line:

```
when(dependency.sample()).thenReturn("Hello, Mock");
```

Instead of `dependency.sample()` you should put whatever method  of `MyControllerDependency` class  your controller call when you send a `GET` request to `/api/test/restpoint` path and with `thenReturn("Hello, Mock")` you define what is the mocked output of that method (when it gets called by your controller in your Unit test).

Comment: Thanks for reponse, but that is not the problem at all. for your sake I'll update the MockBehaviour line... the problem I requested is related to testcase spring context startup... so even if I delete all the code in the Test method and do assert(true) it will still fail

Comment: I updated the question, to avoid the distraction due to multiple information